# logica como llevar el control de pagos y abonos de un prestamo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hola estoy realizando una aplicacion de prestamos de dinero y tengo las siguientes tablas

```
TBLPRESTAMO (idprestamo, idcliente, capital, cuotas,tasaInteres, fechaprestamo, estado)
TBLAMORTIZACION (prestamoId,cuota, pagoCapital, pagoInteres, fechaVenc, estado)
TBLPAGO (prestamoId, valorPago, fechapago,nroCuota) //aqui guardo el idprestamo vel valor pagado, lafecha de pago, numero de cuota que cancela
TBLABONO ( prestamoId, valorAbono, fechaAbono, tipoAbono ) // aqui guardo lo mismo que en la tblpago a diferencia el tipoAbono si es capital o interes
```

cuando guardo un prestamo me guarda la amortizacion en la `TBLAMORTIZACION`
cuando realizo un pago lo guarda en la TBLPAGO y actualizo el estado de la cuota que pago en la `TBLAMORTIZACION`
cuando realizo un abono ya sea de interes o capital lo guardo en la  `TBLABONO`

el problema esta que no se controlar los abonos de capital e interes

ejemplo
prestamo de 1.000.000 al 10% en 5 cuotas en la TBLAMORTIZACION me guarda asi

```
 prestamoId - cuota - pagoCapital - pagoInteres - fechaVenc -  estado  
   1            1      250.000       100.000       26/08/2019  pagado
   1            2      250.000       100.000       26/09/2019  pendiente
   1            3      250.000       100.000       26/10/2019  pendiente
   1            4      250.000       100.000       26/11/2019  pendiente
```

cuando hago un pago lo guardo en la `TBLPAGO` y me cambia el estado de la cuota en la `TBLAMORTIZACION` 
cuando hago un abono de interes o capital lo guardono en la TBLABONO y si es capital lo descuanto del capital, pero cuando es interes no se como descontarlo o si mis no tablas estan bien diseñadas cualquier ayuda, orientacion le agradezco.

Comment: No se que que formula estas aplicando, quizas deberias aclararnos primero los requisitos y como calcular lo que quieres. Entiendo que el 10% de 1M es 100K, pero si cada mes le cobras 100K (4 meses) no hablamos de un 10% si no de un 40% (o lo que es lo mismo usura XD). Trata de explicar mejor el problema para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: si la persona no ha pagado cuotas y solo a abonado un interes de 100.000 que se guarda en la TLBABONO pero la persona a la 3 cuota quiere pagar todo por adelantado como calcularia el total a pagar, tambien quiero saber si son cecesarias las dos tablas TBLPAGO y TBLABONO

Comment: alguna idea de como lo podria hacer mejor? por favor

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo que uso y a ver si te sirve.
Las tablas que comentas si son necesarias, dependerá un poco de la lógica que lleve la aplicación y si éstas hacen su labor a la hora de realizar las consultas a la BD.
En el ejemplo,hay un campo que refleja los intereses totales del préstamo, por lo que a la hora de descontar un pago de intereses lo puedes descontar de ahí.  Ten en cuenta que el pago sólo de intereses no afecta a la amortización de capital. es decir, pagas los intereses pero no disminuyes capital. 
No se si los datos que has puesto en tu ejemplo, son eso, ejemplos y no has querido liarte mucho, pero si no, tengo que decirte que el cálculo que utilizas no es correcto.
Espero que te sirva de guía

```
Datos Generales Préstamo
Capital prestado    Intrereses Totales  Deuda Total     TAE
150.000,00                 77.666,18    227.666,18     3,04%

Nº cuota Capital Inicial Cuota  Amortización Intereses Capital Pendiente
    1   150.000,00       632,41     257,41     375,00     149.742,59
    2   149.742,59       632,41     258,05     374,36     149.484,54
    3   149.484,54       632,41     258,69     373,71     149.225,85
    4   149.225,85       632,41     259,34     373,06     148.966,51
    5   148.966,51       632,41     259,99     372,42     148.706,52
    6   148.706,52       632,41     260,64     371,77     148.445,88
    ...
```

Comment: tengo un poco mas claro esto, pero si la persona solo paga interes y se pasa del valor de intereses totales que esta en la amortizacion que debo hacer

Comment: Si te refieres a que por ejemplo, en la cuota número 5, pagase una cantidad que superase los intereses de esa cuota, lo que tienes que hacer es liquidar los intereses que correspondan a la cuota número 5 que hemos puesto de ejemplo y el resto iría a la amortización de capital. En tu aplicación deberás controlar dichos pagos parciales.